# Visual Studio Code: keybinding to change document syntax highlighting to JSON

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a keybinding to change the current text document language to JSON. Here is what I am trying:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+j",
    "command": "vscode.languages.setTextDocumentLanguage",
    "args": {"document":"active_doc", "languageId": "json"}
}
```

VSCode says 
`command 'vscode.languages.setTextDocumentLanguage' not found`

I understand that this is a function and not a command, so the syntax must be different. Is there a way to tweak my syntax to make this work, or is there an extension that might make this work?
 Thanks in advance

[Here is an example of the function being called in JavaScript from another extension](https://github.com/mechatroner/vscode_rainbow_csv/search?q=setTextDocumentLanguage&unscoped_q=setTextDocumentLanguage)

[Similar question posted prior to the creation of the function I am trying to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639887/how-can-i-create-a-custom-keybinding-to-change-syntax-highlighting-to-a-specific)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension to change language of active editor from a keybinding:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+8",
    "command": "changeLanguageMode.change",
    "args": "typescript"
}
```

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.change-language-mode